# Nesting ancestor rules in LESS

Tags: css, nested, less, ancestor

I have a LESS file where I've wrapped a whole bunch of rules in a body class:

```
body.programme {

    #VideoWrapper {
        border: 1px solid red;
        }

    etc...

    }
```

However I want to change the style of #VideoWrapper if another class is present in body. I thought I might be able to do the following...

```
body.programme {

    #VideoWrapper {
        border: 1px solid red;

        body.inside & {
            border: 1px solid yellow;
            }

        }

    etc...

    }
```

Basically I'm trying to output the following CSS rules:

```
body.programme #VideoWrapper {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
body.programme.inside #VideoWrapper {
    border: 1px solid yellow;
}
```

Is this even possible in LESS without pulling the rules out of the parent body.programme wrapper?

Comment: I never saw such solution... but I'm interested too if this is possible :D

Comment: If those are the CSS rules you want, why don't you just write them that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using the ampersand selector ought to do the trick, something like this:

```
body.programme {
    #VideoWrapper {
        // Your styles 
    }
    &.inside {
        #VideoWrapper {
            // Different styles 
        }
    }
}
```

Another approach (which alas means moving those styles out of `body`) might be:

```
#VideoWrapper {
    // generic styles
    body.programme & {
        // special styles 
    }
    body.programme.inside & {
        // further styles 
    }
}
```

But that might not satisfy your OCD either.

Comment: His point, it would appear, is that he desperately wants to avoid writing `#VideoWrapper` twice.

Comment: Correct! OCD! :)

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to do exactly what you want without refactoring - see my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks, yea - I think I have to settle  for refactoring my LESS a little. Oh well... thanks! :)